# I need custom segue when dismissing view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to dismiss present viewController and I need custom segue to implement that.

```
- (void)perform {
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *sourceTabBarController = sourceViewController.parentViewController.parentViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationViewController.view.bounds.size);
    [destinationViewController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *destinationViewControllerImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView *destinationViewControllerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:destinationViewControllerImage];
    destinationViewControllerImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    destinationViewControllerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(destinationViewController.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(destinationViewController.view.frame));

    [destinationViewController.view insertSubview:destinationViewControllerImageView atIndex:1];

    // Add animations
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         destinationViewControllerImageView.center = CGPointMake(-CGRectGetWidth(destinationViewControllerImageView.frame) / 2, -(CGRectGetHeight(destinationViewControllerImageView.frame) / 2));
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO completion:nil];
                     }];


}
```

It works fine but with no animation :(

Answer (score 1):

you are setting animated to NO here - may be problem is here

[[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO completion:nil];

set it to animated:YES

Comment: when i return back tab bar is hiding...... animation is not similar to dismiss ..its sowing something other

Comment: please check your viewWillAppear problem is there.. or can post more code??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not because of setting the `animated:` to `NO`, rather it is because the animation is being interrupted; hence, `presentViewController` within the `completion block` is called immediately.

Instead, try wrapping your `presentViewController:` code within a `if`-clause like so:

```
if(finished)
{
     [[self sourceViewController] presentViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Since your animation duration is only `0.4f`, you wouldn't really see it, because it happens so fast. Try setting the duration longer, then you would be able to see your `destinationViewControllerImageView` animates to its position *before* `presentViewController` is called.

I ran a quick test with animating `opacity`; it should work as expected.

Hope this helps.